# How do I create an ellipse bubble chart?

Tags: plotting

I have some data that I would like to plot as a bubble chart. The data is formatted as {{val1_mean,val1_sd,val2_mean,val2_sd},{val1_mean,......}}. What I would like to do is plot a bubble chart where the x/y location of the bubble is val1_mean,val2_mean and the width/height of the bubble is val1_sd,val2_sd.

So far I've been able to do circular bubble charts with the inbuilt function but am a bit lost as to how to make the bubbles ellipses instead of circles.

Here's the code I've written so far;

```
bubleData={{1.88308*10^6, 1024.85, 149446., 6636.62}, {1.98345*10^6, 15022.5, 
126966., 7071.75}, {1.94677*10^6, 9281.83, 131930., 
7435.15}, {1.88308*10^6, 1024.85, 127423., 8718.36}};
BubbleChart[bubbleData[[All, 1 ;; 3]],ChartStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.5]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To use `BubbleChart` as you have indicated in your comment to Jonathan's answer, a bit of work is required. First, `BubbleChart` expects data of the form:

```
{x, y, w}
```

So, we need to turn your data into something like that, but we need to take a pointer from the [documentation](http://wolfram.com/xid/0mlgii2uq4yn-hwvzt8) to include all of the data. To do that, we add the extra information as metadata:

```
{#1, #2, 1} -> {##3}& @@@ bubbledata
```

which returns

```
{{1.88308*10^6, 1024.85, 1} -> {149446., 6636.62}, 
 {1.98345*10^6, 15022.5, 1} -> {126966., 7071.75}, 
 {1.94677*10^6, 9281.83, 1} -> {131930., 7435.15}, 
 {1.88308*10^6, 1024.85, 1} -> {127423., 8718.36}}
```

where the `1` acts as a placeholder. Now we create a custom `ChartElementFunction`:

```
f[_, v_, {meta_}, ___] := Disk[Most @ v, meta]
```

where I determined from experimentation that the third parameter is the data point itself, so we strip off the last element. Putting it all together,

```
BubbleChart[{#1, #2, 1} -> {##3}& @@@ bubbledata, 
  ChartElementFunction -> f, 
  PlotRange -> {{1.70*^6, 2.15*^6}, {-10000, 23000}},
  PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"
]
```

gives

[image: bubble chart with ellipses]

Two things to note about the final code:

1. The `PlotRange` required a lot of manual adjustment.
2. I used `PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"` to eliminate the mouseover effects that are normally there as they only show the placeholder I used, so they are not that useful here.

Comment: Many thanks @rcollyer. I spent a while experimenting with `ChartElementFunction` but didn't quite get to that point.

Comment: @JonathanShock Thanks. I hadn't thought of using `ChartElements`, so I think we're even. :)

Comment: I'm getting a message "f is not a Graphics primitive or directive." in Mathematica 9.0.1.0

Comment: @Cam, me too, with 9.0.0.0.

Comment: @Cam I was to, for a bit on 9.0.1, and I don't remember how I solved it. I'll look at it in a bit.

Comment: @Cam there was an extra `_` in the pattern.

Comment: @JonathanShock fixed it.

Answer (score 6):

It seems to be possible with `ChartElementsFunction` but by default `BubbleChart` just takes 3 arguments so you would have to play with this option. To do precisely what you want it seems easier to define your own graphics object like this:

```
ellipse[v_]:=Disk[{v[[1]],v[[2]]},{v[[3]]/10,v[[4]]/10}]
datatoplot=RandomReal[1, {10, 4}];
blankplot=ListPlot[{0, 0},PlotStyle->White,PlotRange->{{-0.1, 1.1},{-0.1,1.1}}];
Show[blankplot, Graphics[Style[ellipse[#], Blue] & /@ datatoplot]]
```

and you'll get something like this:

[image]

Edit:

(Edit 2: The following is not currently correct. As pointed out by @Cam, the `ChartElements` are not showing up with the correct `AspectRatio`)

It was pointed out that there are some features of `BubbleChart` which are desirable, so I'll suggest the following:

```
datatoplot = RandomReal[1, {10, 4}];
ellipse[v_] := Disk[{v[[1]], v[[2]]}, {v[[3]]/10, v[[4]]/10}];
ce=Show[Graphics[Style[ellipse[#], Blue]]] & /@ datatoplot;
Show[BubbleChart[{datatoplot[[;; , ;; 3]][[#]]},ChartElements -> ce[[#]]] & /@ Range[Length[datatoplot]], PlotRange -> All]
```

Which should allow you to define the ellipses as you want and plot each `ChartElement` individually. In this case there are as many `BubblePlots` as there are datapoints and they are all then shown together. This may not be the most efficient way but it was the best way I found to have the `ChartElements` show up correctly.

This produces the plot below (plot points differ from the above as they are randomly generated):

[image: bubble chart]

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. If at all possible I'd like the keep the bubble chart. I'm currently using a tool tip so when you place your mouse over the bubble a table appears showing the values (I left that bit out of the question because I didn't want to complicate things). The bubble chart also highlights the bubble you're mouse is over which looks nice.

Comment: Fair enough. I've written an alternative version which should include what you want.

Comment: Incidentally, your use of `Show` is not necessary as you are not combining `Graphics` objects.

Comment: Does this solution mean I have to scale my data?

Comment: @Cam, that depends. If the data are between 0 and 1 and the standard deviations take on a large range of values over that range then the ellipses are likely to overlap. This is a matter of the nature of the data. If this were a problem you might think about decreasing the `Opacity` of the Graphics objects.

@rcollyer, I have a `Table` of `BubbleCharts` as I'm setting it up as `BubbleChart[data[[#]],ChartElement->ce[[#]]]&/@Range[data]` so I used Show. I'm sure there is a way to include this all in one `BubbleChart`, but this was the easiest way I found to present it.

Comment: Indeed. What I hope to be able to do with this tool is to be able to see in 2d space whether various data points are distinct. I'd expect to see some overlap.

Comment: @Cam In which case it sounds like you won't need to rescale.

Comment: @Jonathan. I was just asking because if I plot datatoplot = {{1, 2, 3, 4}} with this method I get an ellipse that's 0.8 high and 0.4 wide. I would have expected to get width=3 and height=4. Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: I had rescaled the semimajor and minor axes in my example so that the values didn't overlap too much. If you remove the divisions by 1/10th you should get a non-rescaled plot.

Comment: @JonathanShock unfortunately that doesn't seem to work. When I use datatoplot = {{1, 2, 0.5, 0.7}, {10, 5, 10, 0.2}} the ellipses appear in the right place but the width/height are clearly incorrect. This is a little confusing.

Comment: @Cam, you are right. Sorry for the confusion. I've been playing with this and can't seem to get the `ChartElements` to show up correctly. I'll play some more and if I can't get it, I'll put this as a question on its own.

Comment: @Cam, incidentally, you could adapt my first example by using `Mouseover` to get the tooltip you were looking for.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8543/discussion-between-jonathan-shock-and-cam)

Comment: @Jonathan thanks for all your help. Ultimately your answer may be the best because with rcollyers answer you lose the tool tip which is a bit of a problem for me (even if I didn't say that in the question).