# Scaling of ChartElements

Tags: plotting, scaling

In attempting to answer [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24241/how-do-i-create-an-ellipse-bubble-chart/24246#24246) question from @Cam on `BubbleCharts` with elliptical bubbles, I suggested using separate `ChartElements` which themselves could be ellipses. My idea was to define them as regular graphics objects and use them like this:

```
datatoplot = {{1, 2, 0.5, 0.7}, {10, 5, 10, 0.2}};
ellipse[v_] := Disk[{v[[1]], v[[2]]}, {v[[3]]/10, v[[4]]/10}];
ce = Graphics[Style[ellipse[#], Blue]] & /@ datatoplot;
Show[BubbleChart[{datatoplot[[;; , ;; 3]][[#]]},ChartElements->ce[[#]]]&/@{1,2}, PlotRange -> All]
```

However, while the objects I've called `ce` above are indeed ellipses, they get rescaled when they are used as ChartElements and their ellipsicity is undone (or at least altered).

It seems in the help section for `ChartElements` that the format to define the width and height is to give

```
ChartElements->{g,{w,h}}
```

but this gives an error message when I try and implement it naively (with an arbitrary scaling of `{0.3,0.6}`). Trying it by hand:

```
Show[BubbleChart[{datatoplot[[;; , ;; 3]][[#]]},ChartElements -> {ce[[#]], {0.3, 0.6}}]&/@{1,2}, PlotRange -> All]
```

gives me the error shown here:

[image: error message]

Does anyone know how to correctly implement the scaling for `ChartElements`? Is it that the elements should somehow be different from regular Graphics objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing the error is because `BubbleChart` doesn't let you specify the width and height of chart elements because it determines them itself. You can do it with `ChartElementFunction` though.

```
data = {{1, 2, 0.5, 0.7}, {10, 5, 10, 0.2}};
cef[___] := Disk[{#1, #2}, {#3, #4}] & @@ data[[++i]]
BubbleChart[i = 0; data[[All, ;; 3]], ChartElementFunction -> cef]
```

[image: bubble chart with ellipses]

Comment: Yes, I think you are probably right on this. The whole point of the `BubbleChart` is that it specifies the size by the third elements in the list of data that you give it. I hadn't thought of that. I'll see if anyone else answers, but this sounds like a fair response.